# Python histogram of RMS amplitude of audio file

Tags: python, audio, histogram, rms, amplitude

I would like to make a histogram that bins [RMS amplitude](https://www.hackaudio.com/digital-signal-processing/amplitude/rms-amplitude/) for an audio file. The goal is to show, for the full duration of the file, how much of the signal is at each amplitude level. Is there a Python package with a function for this? If not, how can it be coded?

I would also like to set the frequency range over which the analysis will be computed, e.g. between 1 and 6 kHz.

I have the following as a crude start, though I don't yet understand what it represents, and it certainly does not use RMS:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   
Fs, data = wavfile.read('file') 
print('data =',data)
print('number of samples in data =',len(data))

subset = data[0:44100] 
subset = abs(subset)
print('number of samples in subset =',len(subset))

plt.hist(subset, bins='auto')  
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you include what `plt.show()` shows? also, are you using scipy's `wavfile.read` function? if so, make sure to import scipy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no special function in `numpy` for RMS, but you can do it like this

```
RMS = np.sqrt(np.mean(x**2))
```

And the question is, for which data (for which `x`) do you want to calculate the RMS.
For example, you can apply RMS for each sample, than assuming you only have one channel in your wav-file:

```
length = data.shape[0] / Fs
print(f"length = {length}s")

RMS = lambda x: np.sqrt(np.mean(x**2))

sample = np.arange(int(length))
RMS_of_sample = np.zeros(sample.shape)
for ns in sample:
    # here you can apply the frequency window for the sample 
    RMS_of_sample[ns] = RMS(data[ns*Fs:(ns+1)*Fs])

plt.hist(RMS_of_sample, label="Left channel")
plt.show()
```

here you can also apply some [signal windows](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.window.html).
This code gives you something like this

[image]

for incoming signal:

[image]

---

**ADDITION to the question in the comment regarding  full/partial frequency range**

If you want to analyze a complete signal in a certain frequency domain, you can apply, for example, simple filter (rectangular frequency window) for the frequency range `[filter_freq_min, filter_freq_max]` like this:

```
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft, fftfreq

filter_freq_min = 1000 # Hz
filter_freq_max = 2000 # Hz

freq = fftfreq(len(data), 1 / Fs)
data_fft = fft(data)

condition = np.logical_or(abs(freq) <= filter_freq_min, abs(freq) >= filter_freq_max)
filtered_data_fft = np.copy(data_fft)
filtered_data_fft [condition] = 0
filtered_data = np.real(ifft(filtered_data_fft ))

# show fft for incoming signal (blue) and filtered signal (orange) 
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(data_fft),'.')
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(filtered_data_fft ),'.')
plt.xlim( [10, Fs/2] )
plt.xlabel( 'Frequency (Hz)' )
plt.show()

# check RMS for filtered and unfiltered signal
print(RMS(filtered_data),RMS(data))
```

[image]

In this way, you can cycle through the required frequency ranges.

To play sound directly in Python, you can use

```
import sounddevice as sd # For playing/recording audio
sd.play(data, Fs)
sd.play(filtered_data, Fs)
```

Comment: Thank you! When I apply this code with no adjustments, my histogram has only a single bar, which I assume means my bin size is equal to the full frequency range. How can I make each bar represent the RMS amplitude in proportionally equal frequency bins on the log scale of frequency? For instance, each bin equalling one octave or one fifth?

Comment: Perhaps the addition in my answer will help you create an RMS histogram for a complete signal in each frequency range.